# Can Natsu eat fire from objects he burns?

Tags: fairy-tail

I have been thinking that if Natsu can't eat his own fire, can he set some object on fire using his magic and then eat that fire??

Comment: wouldn't that still be his fire since it's his magic which starts the fire

Comment: But the object is burning and kind of producing new flames?

Comment: that might be true but i don't know enough about fires and physics to know

Comment: In the end, that will be his fire. As stated in one of the chapters (Finding), he cannot eat his own flames. It was even said by gray when he was fighting silvers. 
I think the only possibility of him eating flames started by himself is by taking a match stick and burning some wood,etc. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Fairy Tail Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Dragon_Slayer_Magic)

> In addition, the user can consume external sources of fire to restore their body to a healthy state and regain their reserves of strength, something that also makes them immune to most types of fire, due to their capability of nullifying fire-based attacks by sucking them in and eating them; the consumed fire also seems to possess a different “taste” according to its “quality”. **However, the user can’t eat their own flames, or things set on fire by them, to reinvigorate themselves.**